# Xcode 15: No "Source Control" menu item in the menu bar

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

In Xcode 15 there is no more "Source Control" menu item. Where has it gone and how to enable it back if possible?

[image]

In the previous versions of Xcode there definitely was such a button:
[image]

And the official documentation clearly mentions that tab as well:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-your-xcode-project-to-use-source-control

> To copy a remote repository, select Source Control > Clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the menu items are still there, but under "Integrate" instead of "Source Control."

[image: Screenshot of 'Integrate' menu selected]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Inded, I haven't used Xcode's Source Control for a while and didn't notice this change.